# PySide - Group radioButton in a loop

Tags: python, pyside2

I have a problem when trying to group, radioButton generated in a loop, together so that each line has its one buttonGroup and can be checked separetly.

Here is a stripped version of my code:

```
def ui_layout(self):
    self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
    self.setLayout(self.main_layout)

    attrs = ['a', 'b']

    for attr in attrs:

        buttonGroup = QButtonGroup()

        self.attr_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.attr_layout)

        self.rb1 = QRadioButton('{}_rb1'.format(attr))
        self.attr_layout.addWidget(self.rb1)
        buttonGroup.addButton(self.rb1)

        self.rb2 = QRadioButton('{}_rb2'.format(attr))
        self.attr_layout.addWidget(self.rb2)
        buttonGroup.addButton(self.rb2)
```

All I get is this :

[image: radioButton behaving all in the same buttonGrp]

Here's the full code if you wanna try stuff : https://pastebin.com/3vJ4DXER

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QRadioButton, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout,
                             QButtonGroup, QApplication, QWidget)

class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):

        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)

        attrs            = ['a', 'b']
        self.buttonGroup = ['a', 'b']
        for i, attr in enumerate(attrs):
            self.buttonGroup[i] = QButtonGroup()

            self.attr_layout = QHBoxLayout()
            self.main_layout.addLayout(self.attr_layout)

            self.rb1 = QRadioButton('{}_rb1'.format(attr))
            self.attr_layout.addWidget(self.rb1)
            self.buttonGroup[i].addButton(self.rb1)

            self.rb2 = QRadioButton('{}_rb2'.format(attr))
            self.attr_layout.addWidget(self.rb2)
            self.buttonGroup[i].addButton(self.rb2)    

            self.buttonGroup[i].buttonClicked.connect(self.check_button)

    def check_button(self, radioButton):
        print("radioButton-> `{}`".format(radioButton.text()))

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
a_window = Window()
a_window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Well it works thank you very much.
But I don't understand, isn't it creating a new QButtonGroup() object at each loop when I was doing "buttonGroup = QButtonGroup()" ?
And if it is creating a new object at each loop, each radioButtons in a loop should be under the newly created buttonGroup object and not the same than in the previous loop, isn't it?

Comment: "buttonGroup = QButtonGroup()" - is it creating a new QButtonGroup() object.
But when you exit the loop, you will only have one (last) QButtonGroup () object